# Security and cookie practices for an API of a website

Tags: web-applications, security, web-api

I'd like to create a web API. It would be used on my websites and potentially by others as well. I intend to use a single token to authorise users. You see, this API acts as an OAuth2 client (or medium, I don't quite know how to express it) so it needs to be a front-end of sorts in itself to achieve redirecting the user through the authorisation. However, I'm a bit shaky on how I should go about it despite looking at several resources detailing security practices and general specifications.

Would it be reasonable to set the authorisation token as a HTTP-only cookie? Of course not the result of OAuth, but a generated one.

If I read Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) right, using HTTP-only cookies would allow me to set cookies for individual users, with no way of the websites using the API having access to it. And when they send a request, the cookie would automatically be added to it.

What other security practices should I employ? So far I've gathered a list of header and cookie options:

- HTTP-only cookies: seem to be the way to go
- Secure cookies: packaged with HTTP-only
- <strike>Same-site cookies</strike>: seems like they would prevent other websites from using the API
- `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=year; includeSubDomains` surely a no-brainer
- `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' *.example.com` I feel like this doesn't apply to APIs but rather front-ends
- `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` honestly, I don't quite know
- `X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block` used as a backup for a well-defined `CSP` that is not supported on some browser

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this for a web API or a web site? If it's an API, I don't know what you mean by "redirecting the user." If there is no browser involved, there is no Javascript, so there is little use to using the `HttpOnly` flag, and there is no MIME sniffing so there is no point `X-Content-Type-Options` header.. I also doubt there is much use to restricting iFrame use.

Comment: @JohnWu That's precisely the problem. OAuth 2 requires a series of redirects, which a pure API cannot perform, and I'd like to handle the tokens myself. But I do intend to create a web site as a front end of this API.